# How do I enable desktop notifications in Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, chromium-embedded

How do I enable [desktop notifications](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications) in [Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)?

When I load my url in Google Chrome, window.webkitNotifications is non-null.
When I load my url in my embedded CEF browser,  window.webkitNotifications is null.

```
 if(!window.webkitNotifications) {
    alert("You need to use The Google Chrome Browser to get this feature!");
    return false;
 }
```

Are desktop notifications supported in CEF?  If so, how do I enable them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, current CEF versions don't support this feature.
I also needed this functionality in my project. I ended up implementing it myself, under a different namespace with slightly different functionality.

So you can implement it yourself using [JS Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration). Might take some work, but it'll get you what you need.

You can also try asking that question in the [CEF Support Forum](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=6), you might get a better answer than "do it yourself".

I'd love to hear a better solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion that it is not supported yet.  I have been working with the JavaScript extensions and so far so good (although I am not there yet!

Comment: Anyone of you guys willing to share his work? I'm stuck in the same spot.